# Why are some solutions not building completely with TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm noticing some solutions in Team Foundation Server 2008 won't build completely. As in, some number of the projects in the solution succeed but then one fails. The particular failing project says I’m missing an assembly reference. But I'm not - the project has the reference. It builds fine on my PC. I'm looking at the .csproj file that the build agent pulled down and it has the reference, too (it's line-for-line identical to the project I'm building).

The reference in question is to another project in the solution. At first I thought it wasn't building projects in the right order but the build log is telling me that it did (i.e., the project which the reference is in reference to built successfully). So my guess is that somehow on this project (and I’d say about 10-20% of the projects I’m having it build are failing) it’s looking at the wrong folder for assemblies, but I have no idea.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

I did have one Solution which was building things in the wrong order and some Googling seemed to indicate that this was an occasional side-effect of converting a VS2003 SLN file to a VS2008 SLN file (and it was happening in Visual Studio as well), so in that case I made a new SLN from scratch, checked that in "on top" of the problematic one, and it worked fine. But I tried that in the problem above and it didn’t make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it on multicore machines where the project dependencies haven't been setup correctly, meaning that tfs starts a project compiling before it's dependencies are finished compiling.

Comment: hmm - well the dependencies say they're set up correctly within the SLN and the references are all there. This is just baffling

Answer (score 0):

> > At first I thought it wasn't building projects in the right order but the build log is telling me that it did (i.e., the project which the reference is in reference to built successfully).

Define "built successfully."  In particular, make sure the CoreCompile target was invoked and ran to completion.  I've seen cases where a different target on the referenced project was built, but that target was insufficient to generate the output the dependent project needed.  For example, a web project that includes a Silverlight control will call the GetXapOutputFile target on the Silverlight project -- which is fine & dandy, but it's no replacement for CoreCompile.

If this clue isn't enough to resolve your issue, you should probably post a link to the log and/or the msbuild makefiles.